# Selenium Webdriver - The webelements under the iframe are not identified in IE10 where as it is able to identify in chrome and firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on the following version

> Selenium Webdriver : 3.6.0
>
> IE Driver: 3.6.0 32 Bit

```
<iframe src = https://xxxxxxxx.faces >
```

The web elements are under the above mentioned `iframe` and the same is loaded with src url.Switching the iframe using `driver.switchTo.frame(xpath of the frame)`(The frame doesn't have name or id). I can able to switch to frame but on selecting the webelement under the frame getting no such element exception but the same code is working fine in chrome and mozhilla.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: The html code <iframe src="http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:xxxxx/xxxx/xx/clients.faces?hgtb1528887555534" border="0" frameBorder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">   the element is located under this frame so first i am switching to this frame with xpath //iframe[contains(@src,'clients.faces')] and then identifying the element under this but getting error as no such element exception

Comment: Hi all, Please provide any solution for this problem

Comment: You need to update the question with the HTML of the frame tag along with the element HTML

Comment: the html code is too long unable to provide in comments it too long

Comment: so shared via email please check

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Hi All, One more update, The content under the iframe is secured with CSRF token(Cross Site Request Forgery) token, How to crack that it in selenium, do you know how to do that